# Exe файл моментально закрывается, если импортирована библиотека numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Есть код:

```
import numpy
while True:
    print(123)
```

Если сделать из него exe, то файл будет моментально закрываться при открытии, убрав библиотеку numpy, все будет олрайт. Я конечно могу справиться без этой библиотеки, но мне очень интересно, почему она вызывает моментальное закрытие exe. Может быть кто-то знает?)
Если импортировать, допустим только argmin, ничего не меняется

Comment: каким образом строка `import numpy` появилась в вашем примере ?

Comment: Я сделал это для того, чтобы наглядно показать, что ошибка только из-за импорта этой библиотеки, проблема решилась установкой numpy версией 1.15.4

Comment: Запускаем через командную строку. Тогда можно посмотреть ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается установкой более ранней версии numpy. Я даунгрейднул до версии 1.15.4.